# where is XMLHttpRequest object located

Tags: xml, dom

here is the sample ajax code

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

i want to know where is the XMLHttpRequest  object is located...
is it located in xml dom ?
or is it located inside of window object of browser

i serched it in this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window
according to this it is not inside of the window object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLHttpRequest object is located in the window object for modern browsers. You can see in your example code:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

You are checking the window object for an XMLHttpRequest object and if it is present setting your `xmlhttp` variable as an XMLHttpRequest object.

If you want to browse everything your window object to see this for yourself, in Firefox or Chrome it's as simple as typing `window` into your browser's console and pressing enter (which coincidentally works for any object inside the DOM).

Comment: then why this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window
has not mentioned about xmlhttprequest

Comment: According to the to the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#introduction), the XMLHttpRequest object is an API, so it is not included on that overview page as it is not a property, method or event handler for the window object. Documentation on MDN for the XMLHttpRequest object can be found under the Web API Interfaces section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: thx .. can u pls tell me
what are other apis that browser has like this one.... and
why XMLHttpRequest name contains xml part

Comment: The W3C link provided in my first comment explains why XMLHttpRequest isn't a perfect name for the API. The MDN site for all web APIs is down but it would normally be located [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). You can also see what's available to the object by opening it in the console as mentioned above and search on your search engine of choice for whatever you don't recognize that interests you.